# How to find duplicates in a string

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates, boolean-expression

I am working on creating a world game, and I do not want my game to accept duplicate input's by the user, ex: 'mirror'.

I tried finding the duplicates one way but it didn't work, and I do not know how to make my program realize that the inout is a duplicate.

this is my non working code:

```
def checkForDuplicates(userWord):
 


    duplicates=[]

    
            return True
```

I tried setting this statement to true, if any duplicates where found but it didn't work, I was expecting the function to check the users word for duplicate letters, and If there are duplicates the function returns True if not the function returns False.

this is also python programming language

Comment: use python dictionary

Comment: Duplicate words or characters?

Comment: It would help if you defined precisely what you meant by duplicate. For example is `test` have duplicate `t`s or do they need to be next to each other like `bottle`? The example of `mirror` isn't really clear on that point.

Comment: Assuming you mean duplicate letters anywhere in the word, one easy way to check for that is to create a `set()` object out of the word and check its length.  If the set length is smaller than the original word, then it contains duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is your `return` statement is nested inside of your `for` loop so it will always return after checking the first letter. You could move the `return` into an `else` statement so that it returns `True` after the first duplicate letter is found and then put `return False` after it gets all the way through the for loop without hitting any duplicates. (without the `return False` it would return `None` which also is a falsey value)

- note: I changed the capitalization to fit Python standards

Here is a working runnable example

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

def check_for_duplicates(user_word):
    duplicates=[]
    for dup in user_word:
        if dup not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(dup)
        else:
            return True
    return False

print(f'{check_for_duplicates("mirror")=}')
print(f'{check_for_duplicates("marine")=}')
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js" theme="darcula"></script>
```

Comment: @Modulazier this is off topic but how do you the run code snippet thing????

Comment: @Flow do you mean how to run it or how to add it to an answer? It should run when you click the `Run code snippet`, does it not for you? It's possibly it may take a while the first time you run it

Comment: It works just wondering how you did it?

Comment: @Flow check out the docs [here](https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to know if there are repeating characters in a string, we can loop through each character of the string and check if there is another duplicate character by using the string `count(c)` function.

I have made the code you need:

```
def checkForDuplicates(userWord):
    for char in userWord:
        if userWord.count(char) > 1:
            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already identified the problem in the loop. alternatively, if you want to try the `set()` function call.

This might be a more simple more optimized one because `set()` is faster than finding it running a python loop.

```
def has_duplicates(string):
    return len(set(string)) < len(string)
```

Output:

```
print(has_duplicates("Mirror"))  # True
print(has_duplicates("Hello world"))  # True
print(has_duplicates("Helo"))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are making some pretty simple mistakes.**

Return True should be in an else statement instead of the if statement. Also, you need the program to return False if the for loop ends and True hasn't been returned.

**You could implement these suggestions like this:**

```
def checkForDuplicates(userWord):
    duplicates = []
    for dup in userWord:
        if dup not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(dup)
        else:     
            return True
    return False
```

**Output:**

```
print(checkForDuplicates("mirror")) # returns true
print(checkForDuplicates("taco")) # returns false
```

Edit: Modularizer also came to the exact same answer I did.

This returns true if given "mirror" and false if given "cake". I checked for a bunch of other values, and this is working properly.

**Better Implementation Method**

In my above code, I only modified your code, but you would be better off doing in differently.

Like user Faisal Nazik suggested, all you have to do is:

```
def has_duplicates(string):
    return len(set(string)) < len(string)
```